# monitor the values of registers in bits

Tags: avr, atmelstudio, atmega32

I wrote a simple code :

```
start:
ldi r16,12
ldi r17,-56
rjmp start
```

I want to see the values of r16 and r17 in bits in ATMELStudio7
how is it possible?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can visualize the values in different ways. You can use a USART interface to print the values or you use some sort of debugger or some sort of display, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your help , but I am a beginner , would you please give further explanation or a useful link ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a debugger like a [JTAGICE3](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/PartNO/ATJTAGICE3). This device is a programming device and a debugging device which is useful when you want to check internal memories of the processor like registers, RAM, EEPROM, Flash, etc. You can also single-step through your program to watch the results of your operations.

You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAw-7Lq-3tI) video for more information.

A more advanced technique is to use some sort of an interface to visualize the contents of your registers, like the USART to send the data to your PC. But imho this is not very beginner friendly.